# Crawler's "shouldCrawl" event requires boolean returned from axios async function, and can't get them in sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Event `shouldCrawl` belongs to js-crawler's config object, and the callback function it has as value must return boolean in order to tell the crawler whether or not to crawl the URL received as an argument.

I'm using axios and HEAD method to retrieve the resource's headers. Will return true to `shouldCrawl` when content-type contains text/html in order to prevent the crawler from downloading files and garbage.

My code:

```
this.crawler = new Crawler().configure({

    shouldCrawl: async(sUrl)=> {
        
        const crawlWhenHtml = async()=> { //return false;

            return axios({
                url: sUrl,
                method: 'head'

            }).then(res=>{ 
                return (res.headers['content-type'].indexOf('text/html') >= 0? 
                                    true:false);

            }).catch(error=>{
                return  false;
            });
        }

        return await crawlWhenHtml();
    }
});
```

I can't get `shouldCrawl` and `crawlWhenHtml` in sync.

If I make the callback returns false (see commented sentence), `shouldCrawl` ignores it and crawls the URL anyway. This happens since I made the mentioned callback async.

But without making it async I cant't wait for axios completes the request before returning a boolean to `shouldCrawl`.

How can I unravel this?

Comment: I have fixed my problem using another crawler node module: simplecrawler. It is working fine, for now.

Comment: If `shouldCrawl` isn't expecting an asynchronous function, passing one to it won't magically make it work asynchronously. It will call the function synchronously, the return value is a `Promise`, which evaluates as "truthy" (as any object would), which means it crawls.

Comment: Correct. The issue is how to wait for the promise without the program pointer exiting shouldCrawl.